Examining uninitialized heap memory, strange transition at size 1044472
In the following C++ program I am examining how many bytes are zeroed in the uninitialized heap memory.
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>


static void CountZerosNonZeros(size_t nBytes)
{
    char* mem = new char[nBytes];

    size_t count[2] = {};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nBytes; i++)
        count[mem[i] == 0]++;

    delete [] mem;

    std::printf("Zeros:     %7zu\n", count[true]);
    std::printf("Non-zeros: %7zu\n", count[false]);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const size_t nBytes = std::stoull(argv[1]);

    CountZerosNonZeros(nBytes);
}

I compiled this on Visual Studio 2022 v17.10.4 (cl.exe v19.40.33812) to x86-64 binary with optimizations. I found, that

for nBytes <= 1044472 some bytes are not zeroed, while
for nBytes > 1044472 all are zeroed.

What makes this difference?
I couldn't reproduce this on Godbolt, so this is probably an MSVC feature. Also, I am aware, that using uninitialized memory is UB. Still, I think the question is interesting.

You aren't initializing them ... Thus, what you get is what you get. Even reading them is UB, so the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants.

Large allocation requires allocating a new page would be my guess. In Windows freshly allocated pages are zeroed.

@ChrisMM AFAIK know reading from unitialized dynamically allocated memory isn't UB, just indeterminate.

Side note : just use std::atoi instead of sscanf (a "C" function)

@PepijnKramer, the value is indeterminate, but If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined ([basic.indet]/2), so reading the value, and using it for comparison, would produce an indeterminate value, thus UB. At least, that's my understanding, I might be wrong.

Thank you for the comments, I addressed most of them (std::stoull and UB). You don't have to stress, that this is UB. I know, but I'm still curious. I suggest deleting obsolete comments. I will delete this one.

@john: If I call CountZerosNonZeros(1044472) two times, but don't delete [] mem;, theoretically a new page has to be acquired by the program, and the 2nd counting should show that all are zeroed. But they aren't.

"You don't have to stress, that this is UB. I know, but I'm still curious." - I'm curious about why you think trying to reason about UB makes any sense - if there's UB the program is simply broken and you cannot reason about it. End of discussion.

There are times when years of experience, iron-clad target system guarantees, and careful experimentation allow you to take advantage of UB to pull off some really impressive smurf, so I won't call understanding UB completely worthless.

Where do the values of uninitialized variables come from, in practice on real CPUs? and Consistency of undefined behavior for a fixed compiler and Why is the phrase: "undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything it wants" true?

Honestly folks, I think this is an interesting question and I’m a little sad that people would just blindly close it “because it’s UB” - OP knows it is! This affords a good opportunity to dive into the behaviour of malloc/new. The answers can be deep and surprisingly relevant for application security. Although, yes, this is UB, the compiler will generally not do completely asinine things in this case, and reading the assembly should confirm that it does “what you’d expect” - asking the system allocator for a chunk of memory and reading it.

In this case, the allocator is likely reusing existing heap memory right up to the point at which the existing heap is exhausted, or the allocator decides to switch to a straight call to VirtualAlloc (mmap on Linux). The C and C++ standard libraries tend to perform allocations and frees during the startup process, which will explain the non-zero values even though the program does nothing else.
